# Python: Extracting subject and its dependent phrases from text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am trying to follow the thread ([How to extract subjects in a sentence and their respective dependent phrases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763091/how-to-extract-subjects-in-a-sentence-and-their-respective-dependent-phrases)). I also want to extract the subject and its dependent from the text.

```
import spacy
from textpipeliner import PipelineEngine, Context
from textpipeliner.pipes import *

text = 'No Offline Maps! It used to have offline maps but they disappeared. It now has a menu option to watch a video in exchange for maps but it never downloads the map. Makes the app useless to me.'

pipes_structure = [
    SequencePipe([
        FindTokensPipe("VERB/nsubj/*"),
        NamedEntityFilterPipe(),
        NamedEntityExtractorPipe()
    ]),
    FindTokensPipe("VERB"),
    AnyPipe([
        SequencePipe([
            FindTokensPipe("VBD/dobj/NNP"),
            AggregatePipe([
                NamedEntityFilterPipe("GPE"),
                NamedEntityFilterPipe("PERSON")
            ]),
            NamedEntityExtractorPipe()
        ]),
        SequencePipe([
            FindTokensPipe("VBD/**/*/pobj/NNP"),
            AggregatePipe([
                NamedEntityFilterPipe("LOC"),
                NamedEntityFilterPipe("PERSON")
            ]),
            NamedEntityExtractorPipe()
        ])
    ])
]

engine = PipelineEngine(pipes_structure, Context(text), [0, 1, 2])
engine.process()
```

When I ran the above code it throws following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5f5a5c9e8e51> in <module>()
----> 1 engine = PipelineEngine(pipes_structure, Context(text), [0, 1, 2])
      2 engine.process()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textpipeliner/context.py in __init__(self, doc)
      4         self._current_sent_idx = -1
      5         self._paragraph = self._sents[0:9]
----> 6         for s in doc.sents:
      7             self._sents.append(s)
      8         self.doc = doc

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sents'
```

I am not sure where am I making the mistake. Could anyone help in rectifying the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting library.

Your context needs to be a different object. The error says that explicitly. Check the package official [example](https://github.com/krzysiekfonal/textpipeliner#example):

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en")
text = nlp('No Offline Maps! It used to have offline maps but they disappeared. It now has a menu option to watch a video in exchange for maps but it never downloads the map. Makes the app useless to me.')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing in a string as the `text` variable into this line

```
engine = PipelineEngine(pipes_structure, Context(text), [0, 1, 2])
```

Replace line 4 with

```
nlp = spacy.load("en")
text = nlp('No Offline Maps! It used to have offline maps but they disappeared. It now has a menu option to watch a video in exchange for maps but it never downloads the map. Makes the app useless to me.')
```

as this is what they do in the post you referenced.

This way `text` is not a string, but it's whatever type the nlp function spits out, so it works in the 2nd to last line.