# How to extract the subject, verb, object and their relationship of a sentence?

Tags: extract, spacy

My purpose is exactly the same as that in the following post:

[How to extract subjects in a sentence and their respective dependent phrases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763091/how-to-extract-subjects-in-a-sentence-and-their-respective-dependent-phrases)

Therefore, I used the code provided by the original author of this post:

```
SUBJECTS = ["nsubj", "nsubjpass", "csubj", "csubjpass", "agent", "expl"]
OBJECTS = ["dobj", "dative", "attr", "oprd"]
ADJECTIVES = ["acomp", "advcl", "advmod", "amod", "appos", "nn", "nmod", "ccomp", "complm", "hmod", "infmod", "xcomp",
              "rcmod", "poss", " possessive"]
COMPOUNDS = ["compound"]
PREPOSITIONS = ["prep"]


def getSubsFromConjunctions(subs):
    moreSubs = []
    for sub in subs:
        # rights is a generator
        rights = list(sub.rights)
        rightDeps = {tok.lower_ for tok in rights}
        if "and" in rightDeps:
            moreSubs.extend([tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in SUBJECTS or tok.pos_ == "NOUN"])
            if len(moreSubs) > 0:
                moreSubs.extend(getSubsFromConjunctions(moreSubs))
    return moreSubs


def getObjsFromConjunctions(objs):
    moreObjs = []
    for obj in objs:
        # rights is a generator
        rights = list(obj.rights)
        rightDeps = {tok.lower_ for tok in rights}
        if "and" in rightDeps:
            moreObjs.extend([tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS or tok.pos_ == "NOUN"])
            if len(moreObjs) > 0:
                moreObjs.extend(getObjsFromConjunctions(moreObjs))
    return moreObjs


def getVerbsFromConjunctions(verbs):
    moreVerbs = []
    for verb in verbs:
        rightDeps = {tok.lower_ for tok in verb.rights}
        if "and" in rightDeps:
            moreVerbs.extend([tok for tok in verb.rights if tok.pos_ == "VERB"])
            if len(moreVerbs) > 0:
                moreVerbs.extend(getVerbsFromConjunctions(moreVerbs))
    return moreVerbs


def findSubs(tok):
    head = tok.head
    while head.pos_ != "VERB" and head.pos_ != "NOUN" and head.head != head:
        head = head.head
    if head.pos_ == "VERB":
        subs = [tok for tok in head.lefts if tok.dep_ == "SUB"]
        if len(subs) > 0:
            verbNegated = isNegated(head)
            subs.extend(getSubsFromConjunctions(subs))
            return subs, verbNegated
        elif head.head != head:
            return findSubs(head)
    elif head.pos_ == "NOUN":
        return [head], isNegated(tok)
    return [], False


def isNegated(tok):
    negations = {"no", "not", "n't", "never", "none"}
    for dep in list(tok.lefts) + list(tok.rights):
        if dep.lower_ in negations:
            return True
    return False


def findSVs(tokens):
    svs = []
    verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB"]
    for v in verbs:
        subs, verbNegated = getAllSubs(v)
        if len(subs) > 0:
            for sub in subs:
                svs.append((sub.orth_, "!" + v.orth_ if verbNegated else v.orth_))
    return svs


def getObjsFromPrepositions(deps):
    objs = []
    for dep in deps:
        if dep.pos_ == "ADP" and dep.dep_ == "prep":
            objs.extend(
                [tok for tok in dep.rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS or (tok.pos_ == "PRON" and tok.lower_ == "me")])
    return objs


def getAdjectives(toks):
    toks_with_adjectives = []
    for tok in toks:
        adjs = [left for left in tok.lefts if left.dep_ in ADJECTIVES]
        adjs.append(tok)
        adjs.extend([right for right in tok.rights if tok.dep_ in ADJECTIVES])
        tok_with_adj = " ".join([adj.lower_ for adj in adjs])
        toks_with_adjectives.extend(adjs)

    return toks_with_adjectives


def getObjsFromAttrs(deps):
    for dep in deps:
        if dep.pos_ == "NOUN" and dep.dep_ == "attr":
            verbs = [tok for tok in dep.rights if tok.pos_ == "VERB"]
            if len(verbs) > 0:
                for v in verbs:
                    rights = list(v.rights)
                    objs = [tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS]
                    objs.extend(getObjsFromPrepositions(rights))
                    if len(objs) > 0:
                        return v, objs
    return None, None


def getObjFromXComp(deps):
    for dep in deps:
        if dep.pos_ == "VERB" and dep.dep_ == "xcomp":
            v = dep
            rights = list(v.rights)
            objs = [tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS]
            objs.extend(getObjsFromPrepositions(rights))
            if len(objs) > 0:
                return v, objs
    return None, None


def getAllSubs(v):
    verbNegated = isNegated(v)
    subs = [tok for tok in v.lefts if tok.dep_ in SUBJECTS and tok.pos_ != "DET"]
    if len(subs) > 0:
        subs.extend(getSubsFromConjunctions(subs))
    else:
        foundSubs, verbNegated = findSubs(v)
        subs.extend(foundSubs)
    return subs, verbNegated


def getAllObjs(v):
    # rights is a generator
    rights = list(v.rights)
    objs = [tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS]
    objs.extend(getObjsFromPrepositions(rights))

    potentialNewVerb, potentialNewObjs = getObjFromXComp(rights)
    if potentialNewVerb is not None and potentialNewObjs is not None and len(potentialNewObjs) > 0:
        objs.extend(potentialNewObjs)
        v = potentialNewVerb
    if len(objs) > 0:
        objs.extend(getObjsFromConjunctions(objs))
    return v, objs


def getAllObjsWithAdjectives(v):
    # rights is a generator
    rights = list(v.rights)
    objs = [tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in OBJECTS]

    if len(objs) == 0:
        objs = [tok for tok in rights if tok.dep_ in ADJECTIVES]

    objs.extend(getObjsFromPrepositions(rights))

    potentialNewVerb, potentialNewObjs = getObjFromXComp(rights)
    if potentialNewVerb is not None and potentialNewObjs is not None and len(potentialNewObjs) > 0:
        objs.extend(potentialNewObjs)
        v = potentialNewVerb
    if len(objs) > 0:
        objs.extend(getObjsFromConjunctions(objs))
    return v, objs


def findSVAOs(tokens):
    svos = []
    verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB" or tok.dep_ != "aux"]

    for v in verbs:
        subs, verbNegated = getAllSubs(v)
        # hopefully there are subs, if not, don't examine this verb any longer
        if len(subs) > 0:
            v, objs = getAllObjsWithAdjectives(v)
            for sub in subs:
                for obj in objs:
                    objNegated = isNegated(obj)
                    obj_desc_tokens = generate_left_right_adjectives(obj)
                    sub_compound = generate_sub_compound(sub)
                    svos.append((" ".join(tok.lower_ for tok in sub_compound),
                                 "!" + v.lower_ if verbNegated or objNegated else v.lower_,
                                 " ".join(tok.lower_ for tok in obj_desc_tokens)))
    return svos


def generate_sub_compound(sub):
    sub_compunds = []
    for tok in sub.lefts:
        if tok.dep_ in COMPOUNDS:
            sub_compunds.extend(generate_sub_compound(tok))
    sub_compunds.append(sub)
    for tok in sub.rights:
        if tok.dep_ in COMPOUNDS:
            sub_compunds.extend(generate_sub_compound(tok))
    return sub_compunds


def generate_left_right_adjectives(obj):
    obj_desc_tokens = []
    for tok in obj.lefts:
        if tok.dep_ in ADJECTIVES:
            obj_desc_tokens.extend(generate_left_right_adjectives(tok))
    obj_desc_tokens.append(obj)

    for tok in obj.rights:
        if tok.dep_ in ADJECTIVES:
            obj_desc_tokens.extend(generate_left_right_adjectives(tok))

    return obj_desc_tokens


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
sentence = "Lung cancer causes huge mortality to population, and pharmaceutical companies require new drugs as an alternative either synthetic or natural targeting lung cancer. This review highlights the inextricable role of G. lucidum and its bioconstituents in lung cancer signaling for the first time."

doc = nlp(sentence)
print(findSVAOs(doc))
```

But because the version used is different, I made two necessary changes according to the prompts in the comments in the original post.

Change the following code:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
parser = English()
parse = parser(sentence)
print(findSVAOs(parse))
```

To:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp(sentence)
print(findSVAOs(doc))
```

Change the code in findSVAOs:

```
verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB" and tok.dep_ != "aux"]
```

To:

```
verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB" or tok.dep_ != "aux"]
```

When:

```
sentence = "Lung cancer causes huge mortality to population, and pharmaceutical companies require new drugs as an alternative either synthetic or natural targeting lung cancer. This review highlights the inextricable role of G. lucidum and its bioconstituents in lung cancer signaling for the first time."
```

Output:

```
[('lung cancer', 'causes', 'huge mortality'), ('companies', 'require', 'new drugs'), ('review', 'highlights', 'inextricable role')]
```

This is an acceptable result.

But since all the documents I want to analyze are biomedical documents, I hope to use en_core_sci_md to replace en_core_web_md. That is:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_md')
```

However, after I made this replacement, something strange happened.
Now, the output is:

```
[('lung cancer', 'causes', 'huge mortality population'), ('lung cancer', 'causes', 'population'), ('companies', 'require', 'new drugs'), ('review', 'highlights', 'inextricable role lucidum'), ('role', 'bioconstituents', 'signaling first time'), ('bioconstituents', 'signaling', 'first time')]
```

In some ways, the result is indeed better. For example:

`('lung cancer', 'causes', 'huge mortality population')` compared with the previous `('lung cancer', 'causes', 'huge mortality')`.

However, it obviously outputs some redundant items. For example:

`('lung cancer', 'causes', 'huge mortality population')` and `('lung cancer', 'causes', 'population')`

The latter is obviously redundant.

Another example:

`('role', 'bioconstituents', 'signaling first time')` and `('bioconstituents', 'signaling', 'first time')`

The latter is obviously redundant.

How can I remove these redundant items when using en_core_sci_md?

Answer (score 0):

This change does not make sense, the result is going to be verbs plus any other non-`aux` tokens:

> Change the code in findSVAOs:
>
> ```
> verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB" and tok.dep_ != "aux"]
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> verbs = [tok for tok in tokens if tok.pos_ == "VERB" or tok.dep_ != "aux"]
> ```